# MVC3 Controller Action Result 'Remember' Passed-in Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two action results in my Controller. Overview and About.

```
public ActionResult Overview(int id)
{
    return View(new OverviewModel() { Project = db.People.Find(id) });
}

public ActionResult About(int id)
{
    return View(new AboutModel() { Project = db.People.Find(id) });
}
```

I would like to remember the id that was passed in to Overview and use it on the About as the default. I don't know how to keep this Id constant while the user switches tabs from Overview to About.

Comment: Why wouldn't putting it in session work?

Comment: What do you mean by putting it in the session?

Comment: Like Brandon's answer, except with Session instead of TempData

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try storing the id in TempData. Maybe something like this (not tested)

```
public ActionResult Overview(int id)
{
    TempData["YourId"] = id;
    return View(new OverviewModel() { Project = db.People.Find(id) });
}

public ActionResult About(int? id)
{
    id = id ?? int.Parse(TempData["YourId"].ToString());
    return View(new AboutModel() { Project = db.People.Find(id) });
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what TempData is? Thanks this does work.

Comment: @dnxviral, TempData is like ViewData, except that it persists for two successive requests making it useful for things like passing data between two different controller actions.

Comment: TempData in MVC actually persists until retrieved. As an FYI Tempdata is actually stored in a users SessionState so it is more like SessionData than ViewData. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Is there a way to keep the data persistent, while retrieving it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hidden html attribute if this data is not sensitive. it worked wonders for us and it saved us alot of processing power.